# ¿Cómo se llaman esas cosas que parecen un trozo de parada de autobús y se usan para poner publicidad?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

Me refiero a cosas como esta:

[image]

Los términos que conozco son:

- [**Valla publicitaria**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bJAo3Kw#FzLEEb0): pero a mí no me parece una valla, la verdad. Yo ese término lo asocio más bien a esos grandes carteles que se ven desde la carretera ([ver imágenes de Google](https://www.google.es/search?q=valla%20publicitaria&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGh-SBjOLaAhWCQJoKHQGuAWYQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=893)). Esto por lo que pregunto es más pequeño y solo se encuentra en los entornos urbanos.
- [**Marquesina**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OT6Ecog): es cierto que estos postes se parecen mucho a las marquesinas de las paradas de autobús. Pero "marquesina" es relativamente genérico ([ver imágenes de Google](https://www.google.es/search?q=marquesina&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP-uXXjeLaAhWiYJoKHQ-fAVoQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=893)), y además su función principal parece ser la de proteger del sol y la lluvia, mientras que lo de la imagen arriba incluida solo sirve para mostrar publicidad.

¿Existe algún término más específico o más técnico con el que referirse a estas no-vallas publicitarias?

Comment: Me ha encantado cómo has descrito el objeto como "un trozo de parada de autobús". :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el mundo de la publicidad y el *marketing*, a estos elementos se les llama normalmente **mupis**:

> **¿Qué es un mupi publicitario?**
>
> La palabra MUPI es en realidad el acrónimo francés de *[mobilier urbain pour l'information](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobilier_urbain_pour_l%27information)*, que en español sería "mobiliario urbano para información". Es un tipo de cartel al aire libre que se suele encontrar en la calle al lado de una parada de autobús. De hecho, mucha gente se refiere a los mupis como marquesinas, aunque en realidad ahora pueden verse en la calle sin que haya una parada de autobús al lado.
>
> <sub>Fuente: [Sírvase usted misme](https://www.google.es/search?q=mupi) (no quiero promocionar ningún sitio particular)</sub>

Otras fuentes definen el acrónimo como "*mobiliario urbano como punto de información*" o como "*mueble urbano para la presentación de la información*", tratando de adaptarlo al español.

Existe otro término todavía más específico, **opi** (acrónimo de "objeto publicitario iluminado"), que se supone que se refiere a los soportes no asociados a ninguna otra estructura, iluminados y cuyo único fin es el publicitario... Pero, por lo que he leído, parece que hay cierta tendencia a usar "mupi" como sustantivo común, tanto para los incluidos en las marquesinas, como para los que encontramos sueltos, como el de la foto de la pregunta.

Comment: Vi que habías comentado algo en el chat y busqué un poco a ver que era eso de "mupis". Lo primero que encontré decía que las siglas eran de " mobiliario urbano para publicidad integrada".

Answer (score 2):

El nombre **paleta publicitaria** es la denominación más común en Chile, y según una [búsqueda en google](https://www.google.com/search?q=paleta%20publicitaria) pareciera usarse también en Perú y al menos a nivel técnico y como nombre alternativo en España. Para llegar a esta conclusión tuve que *des-personalizar* la búsqueda en Google mediante navegación privada y un proxy: [Espero que funcione el link](https://nl.hideproxy.me/go.php?u=Wh%2BQKOZ%2BFlgpYCwVwVwjJ2hgqLB9XHbvApsbbMWSDcZxPjLiSjaAB2yRaUNT1EY%3D&b=5&f=norefer), aunque podría caducar la sesión y no servir más.

El artículo de Wikipedia en castellano sobre la [valla publicitaria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valla_publicitaria) también parece excluir de su definición el objeto que ilustras, pero bajo el acápite de **expositor retroiluminado** define algo que al menos incluye la mayoría de ellos. El concepto, sin embargo, parece ser mucho más amplio, a juzgar por las [imágenes que ofrece Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=expositor%20retroiluminado&tbm=isch) como resultado de su búsqueda.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo visto incluso empresas lo llaman **marquesinas** como tú apuntas:

http://www.interempresas.net/Equipamiento_Municipal/Articulos/37725-La-ciudad-anuncia.html

A lo más que he llegado a oír es "soporte publicitario".

La búsqueda en google de "marquesina publicidad" muestra algunos de estos elementos que tú describes.

https://www.google.com/search?hl=es&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=24HnWq2vJNO6UonWvng&q=marquesina+publicidad&oq=marquesina+publicidad&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0.0.238086.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.j7EAk7ZEFpY

Así que de momento no encuentro ningún término en español para estos objetos.

Otra de las opciones que se me ocurren es **expositor**, pero tampoco es demasiado exacto.

Muy interesante la respuesta de walen, así tendré algo para nombrarlos. La verdad es que no deja de ser curioso cómo es posible que no tengamos palabra para nombrar algo que vemos ¡todos los días! jaja.